# vue set value in session storage not reflecting in data

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am doing an axios call and setting some values to session storage in the main.ts... I was hoping to get that in the next component..but its undefined...
in main.ts

```
saveConfigToSessionStorage()
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    i18n,
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

in the saveurlToSessionStorage , i am just having a method whcih does axios call and sets to session storage

```
import Axios from 'axios'

let url = '/config/myurl.json'
function fetchConfig () {
  return Axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
}


function saveurlToSessionStorage () {
  return fetchConfig().then(respons => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('URL_CONFIG', JSON.stringify(respons))
  })
}

export default saveurlToSessionStorage
```

I can see that the values are getting successfully set in session storage ,but in another component ,when i access it via sessionstorage its undefined.. 
But if the page is refreshed or in another button click , the value works fine..I think it has something to do with Vue rendered the data before axios finishes.. is there a good way to solve it?
Ideally i should be able to get data from server , save to session storage and access it in the data of a component...
Any Vue experts plz

Answer (score 1):

You ignore the promise returned from your fetchConfig() function (which also returns a promise), so your code just executes immediately:

```
saveConfigToSession().then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    i18n,       
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

Comment: Then create a function that wraps `new Vue...` and call that in both `.then()` and `.catch()`,  As far as if it's the right thing to do..You'll delay the booting of the application, so you're going to end up with [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) probably, so you just need to handle that. You could do it with some simple styles on the body.

Comment: Move the `axios` call into the `created` method within a `component` and, as far as reading the value is concerned, use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and in that, check if the sessionStorage has your variable, if not, return a default value - like false, undefined, null, '', 0, "loading", etc.